# How to insert items in std::map without violating MISRA C++ 2008 Required Rule 5-2-12?

Tags: c++, misra

I get this error in PC-Lint (au-misra-cpp.lnt):

> error 1960: (Note -- Violates MISRA C++ 2008 Required Rule 5-2-12,
>   Array type passed to function expecting a pointer)

On this code:

```
_IDs["key"] = "value";
```

The _IDs is declared as:

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> _IDs;
```

also tried changing to:

```
_IDs.insert("key","value");
```

But get the same error.

How do I get the code to be misra compliant?

Comment: Does MISRA have anything to say about not using [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/)? If not, the C++ standard certainly does.

Comment: Yes, it dislikes the underscores. Violates MISRA C++ 2008 Required Rule 17-0-2, Re-use of C++ identifier pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The violated rule is calling `std::string::string(const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())`, which will decay from `char const []` to a char pointer.

The solution, I think, is to cast explicitely to a pointer type:

`_IDs[static_cast<char const *>("key")] = static_cast<char const *>("value");`

However, I would suggest not using (or at least upgrading) a linter that warns when you actually use `std::string`.

Also note that you can't call `std::map::insert` the way you try to do it. There is no overload which takes the key and the value directly, instead there is an overload which takes a pair consisting of the key and the value. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) overload number 1.

Comment: It's obvious how following MISRA produces easier-to-read and easier-to-maintain code :-P

Comment: @Angew: The purpose of MISRA is to make code *harder* to read and maintain. That way, it's less likely that a maintainer will think they understand the code, and make breaking changes based on incomplete knowledge. By transforming the code into gibberish, MISRA forces a complete analysis before making even the smallest change. Hence, more stable code.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Interesting approach. However, I'd say it also makes code much harder to review/verify in the first place. Still, I (kind of) see the point you raise.

Comment: The static cast handles the violation of 5-2-12.

Comment: @Angew: Again, by making these things harder, the obfuscation caused by MISRA forces reviewers to analyse the code in excruciating detail. There is no temptation to gloss over the parts that are "obviously" correct, since nothing is obvious. That would be insane for most software development; but for safety-critical code, you need to treat every line as potentially hostile, and making every line unreadable is one way to achieve that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I'm confused - you weren't being sarcastic?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I was begin half sarcastic; but this seems to be the only real justification for claiming that a pile of insanely restrictive rules can improve software reliability. (Of course, it also serves to bludgeon any potential creativity out of developers, which might also lead to fewer bugs.) Disclaimer: I don't write safety-critical code, and have never experienced rules like this first-hand.

Answer (score 3):

```
// a template function that takes an array of char 
//  and returns a std::string constructed from it
//
// This function safely 'converts' the array to a pointer
//  to it's first element, just like the compiler would
//  normally do, but this should avoid diagnostic messages
//  from very restrictive lint settings that don't approve
//  of passing arrays to functions that expect pointers.
template <typename T, size_t N>
std::string str( T (&arr)[N])
{
    return std::string(&arr[0]);
}
```

Using the above template function, you should be able to get past the linter like so:

```
_IDs[str("key")] = str("value");
```

As an aside - I'm surprised lint isn't complaining that `_IDs` is a reserved name - you should avoid leading underscores in C or C++, especially when used along with caps.